# Help verifying downloaded Kali image

Tags: digital-signature

I am following instructions as shown [here](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images)

- Operating Windows 7, so have downloaded GPG4WIN.
- Next instruction: is to enter this command: `$ wget -q -O - https://www.kali.org/archive-key.asc | gpg --import`
- So, newbie here, ...am I to enter that into Command Prompt? When I do I get error message: *'$' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.*

Comment: The `$` is not part of the command.  That's part of the command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The verification steps assume that you are already using Linux. As you're using Windows, you'll need to follow the manual verification steps from the [Kali download page](http://docs.kali.org/introduction/download-official-kali-linux-images).

To run a SHA1 checksum on Windows, download and install Microsoft's [checksum app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533). Per [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290#bookmark-5), run it with the command:

> fciv.exe -sha1 kali-linux-1.1.0-amd64.iso

Then compare the checksum by hand with what's on the Kali download page.

**Update: 02 July 2017**
Kali is now using SHA256 which is not supported by `fciv`. You can use PowerShell as suggested by @Rоry McCune in the comments. The syntax is

```
Get-FileHash kali-linux-2017.1-amd64.iso -Algorithm sha256
```

You may need to change the filename if you are using a different version of Kali.

Comment: Wow, Neil, thanks. Eureka! It worked for the SHA1sum just as you directed. Am I correct in thinking that MD5 is an equivalent method utilizing a different (MD5) protocol?

Comment: FWIW, you can also use the Get-Filehash powershell cmdlet for this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn520872.aspx

Comment: MD5 and SHA1 are not "protocols", they are mathematical algorithms. [Cryptographic hash algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) to be specific. They have specific properties (see the link) that makes them good for detecting changes in data files such as an ISO.

Comment: @NeilSmithline with the proposed fciv I get a completely different hash produced than on the download page - does it mean, i should not use the image then? Is there a work-around?

Comment: @AliakbarAhmadi - It means that you shouldn't use it as is stated on the Kali download page. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How is ISO verification done with kleopatra on Windows?

For example it worked in qubes-OS:
https://www.qubes-os.org/downloads/

But dont know how to check with Kali.iso as example for 2017.3 version

> http://cdimage.kali.org/kali-2017.3/ 
>    
> #1- downloaded the SHA256SUMS and SHA256SUMS.gpg files from here

And Kali downloaded over torrent has these files: 
 
#2- kali-linux-2017.3-amd64.iso
 
#3- kali-linux-2017.3-amd64.txt.sha256sum

---

Now I added the .asc File -->
downloaded these file:

> https://www.kali.org/archive-key.asc
>   
>  ...and verify that the displayed fingerprint matches the one below
>    7D8D0BF6

And verifying works with SHA256SUMS.gpg from point #1

 but got an error with the checksum downloaded from torrent #2

Tutorial from here:
"https://www.howtogeek.com/246332/how-to-verify-a-downloaded-linux-iso-file-wasnt-tampered-with/"

---

## Solved:

1. Doing it by hand with, select .iso file -> Right Click -> CRC-SHA (coming by 7zip) -> SHA-256 (pressed)
2. Wait a bit until Checksum Information shows:
   `395bc0af107806e5bf06edc6ac4af1f96caaf04f465831abf2f33ce51b73968d`
3. check it by opening the file #1 CHA256SUMS in Editor or Notepad++
4. In the File you see: `395bc0af107806e5bf06edc6ac4af1f96caaf04f465831abf2f33ce51b73968d  kali-linux-2017.3-amd64.iso`

So it's the same.